# How to stop the background-position change when the background image reaches bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-image

Javascript:

```
 (function($) {  

        var x = 0;  
        var y = 0;  
        //cache a reference to the banner  
        var banner = $("#banner");  

        // set initial banner background position  
        banner.css('backgroundPosition', x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');  

        // scroll up background position every 90 milliseconds  
        window.setInterval(function() {  
            banner.css("backgroundPosition", x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');  
            y--;  
            //x--;  

            //if you need to scroll image horizontally -  
            // uncomment x and comment y  

        }, 90);  

})(jQuery);
```

CSS:

```
div#banner {  
  width: 960px;  
  height: 200px;  
  margin: auto;  
  background: url(../images/fotogrph-skyscraping.jpg) repeat 0 0;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="banner"></div>
```

I can not get the position change to stop when the background image reaches the bottom.

Comment: What do you want to do, write it in spanish in a comment and ill help you

Comment: You need to get the dimensions of an image for that to work (and check for the overflow in `setInterval` callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```js
(function($) {  

  var x = 0;  
  var y = 0;  
  //cache a reference to the banner  
  var banner = $("#banner");  

  // set initial banner background position  
  banner.css('backgroundPosition', x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');  

  // scroll up background position every 90 milliseconds  
  var timer = window.setInterval(function() {  
    if(y > -200){
      banner.css("backgroundPosition", x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');  
      y--;  
      //x--;  

      //if you need to scroll image horizontally -  
      // uncomment x and comment y  
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 90);  

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/u0x15oj3/

1. calculate the real height of the image.
2. subtract the height of the `div` shown, this is the threshold.
3. clear the interval when this threshold is reached